# Excel file is not triggering Azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I have setup a very simple azure function that should be triggered whenever an excel file is dropped into my bucket.  However, nothing is happening. Any suggestions?

Here is my functions.json

```json
    {
      "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
      "bindings": [
        {
          "name": "myblob",
          "type": "blobTrigger",
          "direction": "in",
          "path": "excel/{name}.xlsx",
          "connection": "jbucket123_STORAGE"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Here is my **init**.py file.  Any recommendations?

```py
import logging
import pandas as pd
import azure.functions as func

    def main(myblob: func.InputStream):
        logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
                     f"Name: {myblob.name}\n"
                     f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")
        
        df=pd.read_excel(myblob.read())
        logging.info(f"{df}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration looks correct, a few things to doublecheck:

- Do you use a "general-purpose" storage account? Blob triggers are [not supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=csharp) for the legacy "BlobStorage" account types.
- Does a container "excel" exist in your storage account and are you putting your file into it? Does your file end with .xlsx (and not e.g. .xls)?
- If you test locally is the storage account connection string stored under `local.settings.json` like so:

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=[...]",
    "jbucket123_STORAGE": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=[...]"
  }
}
```

- If you run the function in Azure, is the "jbucket123_STORAGE" property set under "Configuration > Application settings"? Did you put all dependencies (e.g. pandas, openpyxl) into your requirements.txt before you published the function?

You might also want to check the "[Log stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/streaming-logs#built-in-log-streaming)" of your function to get more details what your function is doing.